# MYSQL update not working with php variable id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm stuck on a simple MYSQL UPDATE statement; selecting an ID from the database, and then updating a record WHERE ID = $ID. Code:

```
$searchDates = ('SELECT * FROM booking_event WHERE subject != "Closed" AND is_reminded IS NULL AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) >= `starting_date_time` AND NOW() <= `starting_date_time`'); 

$result = mysql_query($searchDates) or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $id = $row['event_id'];

mysql_query("UPDATE booking_event SET is_reminded = 1 WHERE event_id = '$id'") or die (mysql_error()); 

}
```

For some reason it won't update with the ID selected from the database - I've tried using a testID variable and it works fine.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP variables are case sensitive. Most likely your column name in MYSQL will be something like `Event_Id` or any other casing. Using `SELECT *` will return the actual name, so to fetch it you would need `$id = $row['Event_Id']`;

Best thing to be sure you dont have a casing problem, use:

```
SELECT event_id FROM ....
```

and then `$id = $row['event_id'];` will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one query like so:

```
UPDATE booking_event b1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM booking_event 
    WHERE subject != "Closed" 
      AND is_reminded IS NULL 
      AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) >= starting_date_time 
      AND NOW() <= starting_date_time
) b2
SET t1.is_reminded = 1 WHERE b1.event_id = b2.event_id
```